# Storing file paths and names in an array or list for use as arguments for \catchfilebetweentags or \insertgraphics

Tags: paths, datatool, catchfile

**EDITED SOLVED---Thanks @Skillmon**
I have a multitude of compartmentalized tex files each with three tags (all built from the same template with the same tag names). The files are 20001.tex, 20002.tex,... Each has tags: %<*TagA>, %<*TagB>, %<*TagC>. I want to compile a tex document that inserts all the content from the 'A' tags from each file (in order), followed by the 'B' tags, and finally the 'C' tags.

Small File Location Example: C:\Users\User\Documents\Project\Small-Files-Here\20001\20001.tex

Main File: C:\Users\User\Documents\Project\Main-Files\The-Main-File.tex

This structure is used so that relative paths have the same number of levels so that the relative paths are the same when either working on individual small files, or on the main file (for included images, etc.)

Small-File-Paths.csv is located in the same folder at The-Main-File.tex and contains all the individual paths of the small files under the heading "path".

This code does the assembly of the job:

```
\documentclass{book}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.8em}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[margin=1.00 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\begin{document}
    \DTLloaddb{pathlist}{Small-File-Paths.csv}
%   \DTLdisplaydb{pathlist}

    \section*{Put TagA Content Here}
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
    \DTLforeach*{pathlist}{\smallfilepath=path}{
        \item
        \ExecuteMetaData[\smallfilepath]{TagA}
        }
    \end{enumerate}

    \section*{Put TagB Content Here}
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
        \DTLforeach*{pathlist}{\smallfilepath=path}{
            \item
            \ExecuteMetaData[\smallfilepath]{TagB}
        }
    \end{enumerate}

    \section*{Put TagC Content Here}
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
        \DTLforeach*{pathlist}{\smallfilepath=path}{
            \item
            \ExecuteMetaData[\smallfilepath]{TagC}
        }
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're missing braces around the text, you should use `\DTLforeach*{pathlist}{\filepath=path}{\noindent\begin{minipage}...\end{minipage}}` (untested).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, btw.!

Comment: Thanks @Skillmon! And thanks for the quick reply. Yeah, so it *totally* makes sense that I need the braces around the section of code that I want iterated using \DTLforeach. Duh. I can now run it, but it only executes once and then throws an error "Undefined control sequence...."

Comment: Can you please edit your question showing the complete error message you get? For me everything works fine with above code and added braces.

Comment: @Skillmon: As requested, I edited my question. Should be clearer (I hope....)

Comment: @Skillmon, I think I might still be missing a brace in my updated question. Like the line should be: \DTLforeach*{{pathlist}{\smallfilepath=path}{\ExecuteMetaData}[\smallfilepath]{TagA}}
I'll try that when I'm back at my workstation and report back.

Comment: The code in your question has a spurious closing brace after each `\ExecuteMetaData`, the three lines should be `\DTLforeach*{pathlist}{\smallfilepath=path}{\ExecuteMetaData[\smallfilepath]{TagC}}` instead. Also, I can't really debug anything with your current question.

Comment: @Skillmon - thanks for all your help. I struggled to find info on whether or not I was even on the right path to a solution, so discerning if my errors were structural versus syntactical was challenging. In the end, your were right that it was a bracket problem. After I solved that, I had some preamble conflicts between the small files and the main file that were vexing me, but once I found those, everything worked! Now I can get to the work of building my document.

Cheers,
BT

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by syntax errors as discussed/solved in the comments.